# Plot is shifted by 1 unit when overlaying two with same axes (Seaborn/Matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot a regression line over a boxplot using Seaborn.

It seems like the regression plot is being shifted by 1 x-axis unit. This causes the regression to start at `x=2` instead of `x=1`, but with the value of `x=1`. This also causes the regression plot to extend outside the limits of the boxplot (`x=7`). I have recreated the issue using the "tips" dataset to make a minimal reproduceable example and have included an image of the figure.

**How do I resolve this issue so that both plots start and end at the same values?**

**Update**: I ran this code on another machine and it produced the correct plot. So I'm curious about what may be causing the issue on the specific desktop I used originally. (Windows 10, Anacaonda Environment, Python 3.6.10). I'm not running this in a Jupyter notebook

Thanks!

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.boxplot(x="size", y="tip", data=tips, ax=ax)
sns.regplot(x="size", y="tip", data=tips, ax=ax, scatter=False, order=2)

plt.show()
```

[image: Regplot overlayed onto Boxplot]

Comment: How are you using this - Jupyter Notebook? With the exact code you provided, the regression line started at 1 for me. Maybe you have something in your Kernel, that messes with the setup?

Comment: I'm using an Anaconda environment

Comment: But did you  write a script or dir you execute the code in a Notebook with Jupyter or Ipython or something?

Comment: I wrote a script, no Jupyter or Ipython

Comment: Interesting. Is there any more code in the script than this? I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: Since you mentioned my setup, I decided to run this script on my laptop and it works properly, thanks! So I think it may be something with my desktop, but they both have the same environment running the same packages. So I wonder what could cause this issue on my desktop..

Comment: I have the same issue, second plots x values are shifted by exactly one. Software stack tried: linux, python 3.9.8, pandas 1.3.4, matplotlib 3.4.3 and 3.5.0, seaborn 0.11.1 and 0.11.2. Interesting detail: This only happens if one plot is a violin or boxblot, two lineplots do work correctly. Changing the order of box/lineplot does not help.

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

I think issue here is, that seaborn uses matplotlibs boxplot with positions/xticks starting with 0. Thus, in your example `[0,1,...,5]`. The xtickslabels are actually offset by 1:

```
print(ax.get_xticklabels())
[Text(0, 0, '1'), Text(1, 0, '2'), Text(2, 0, '3'), Text(3, 0, '4'), Text(4, 0, '5'), Text(5, 0, '6')]
```

### Workaround

matplotlib allows to set the positions during boxplot construction. However, passing the along with seaborns boxplot will cause an error because the positions argument is actually provided two times.

```
sns.boxplot(x="size", y="tip", data=tips, ax=ax, positions=[1,2,3,4,5,6])
TypeError: matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes.boxplot() got multiple values for keyword argument 'positions'
```

Thus, the only solutions I can imagine is to either to use matplotlib directly without seaborn or to adjust the data to fit the xticks, e.g. by inserting `tips['size'] -= 1` before the second plot in your example.